# Calculating individual distances from a Camera in a 3D world, Java

Tags: java, 3d, render, zbuffer

I am a beginner in 3D rendering, and for a learning experience, I wanted to make my own engine from scratch. I have been looking for a long time, and haven't been able to find something that gives a way to find the distance from the camera of each individual pixel. Does anybody know what I could do to find those values? (I work in Java.)

If anyone wants more details, I will be happy to give!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Consider including the code you have now as part of your question.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "distance from the camera to a pixel"? The camera is the entire viewport, so the distance from the camera to any visible pixel is 0. Maybe you meant the distance from the camera plane from a point further in the z-axis?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, and yes I did mean the distance from the camera to a point further in the z-axis. I am also mostly looking for the maths for the calculation. I haven't really any code currently for the calculations, because the stuff I did have didn't work for obvious reasons.